# SignatureException:Signature length not correct: got 1734 but was expecting 128

Tags: java, security, encryption, digital-signature, signtool

I got one digitally signed **setup.exe** file. It was signed using SignTool.exe.
I also got **myypfxfile.pfx** and **mycertfile.cer**.
I have written below code to veirfy digital signature in java but its giving me SignatureException:Signature length not correct: got 1734 but was expecting 128.
Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Here is detail about **mycertfile.cer**:

Signature Algorithm: sha1RSA

Signature Hash Algorithm: sha1

Valid from 23 July 2014 to 31 July 2015

Public Key: RSA(1024 Bits)
30 81 89 02 81 81 00 ac 27 04 f6 2a 03 56 65 af 70 b3 32 6c 01 c1 7e 05 96 22 5a ae d0 b2 60 cf 64 f7 ff a5 55 ad 91 67 48 03 81 f7 86 a4 69 45 7c fa b9 b5 9e f9 03 ec be da b9 cd 92 b5 f6 a0 5c 52 9a ea ae aa 8d c6 24 d7 16 6c 1c a5 88 c8 b0 5d b5 cc 73 fb 13 14 63 e6 60 e4 e3 8b 3a f4 b8 ea c7 a8 4a c7 43 ae 4d b9 95 35 3b 60 d5 18 f6 fa 15 9d 5e 46 81 11 fa 02 44 d8 95 0a da b3 58 e6 65 cd c7 0d f9 02 03 01 00 01

```
public class CheckCertificate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* Verify a DSA signature */

    /* import encoded public key */

    FileInputStream certfis = null;

    try {
        certfis = new FileInputStream(
                "E:\\GaneshDigiSignature\\mycertfile.cer");

        java.security.cert.CertificateFactory cf = null;
        java.security.cert.Certificate cert = null;

        cf = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        cert = cf.generateCertificate(certfis);

        PublicKey pubKey = cert.getPublicKey();

        /* input the signature bytes */
        FileInputStream sigfis = null;
        byte[] sigToVerify = null;

        sigfis = new FileInputStream(
                "E:\\GaneshDigiSignature\\myypfxfile.pfx");

        sigToVerify = new byte[sigfis.available()];

        sigfis.read(sigToVerify);

        sigfis.close();

        /* create a Signature object and initialize it with the public key */
        Signature sig = null;

        sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

        sig.initVerify(pubKey);

        /* Update and verify the data */

        FileInputStream datafis = null;

        datafis = new FileInputStream("E:\\GaneshDigiSignature\\setup.exe");

        BufferedInputStream bufin = new BufferedInputStream(datafis);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while (bufin.available() != 0) {
            len = bufin.read(buffer);
            sig.update(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        bufin.close();
        boolean verifies = sig.verify(sigToVerify);

        System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("InvalidKeyException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        System.out.println("SignatureException:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        System.out.println("CertificateException:" + e.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of prior code in a try block should be inside the same try block. And look up what it says in the Javadoc of available() about using it to allocate a buffer, or as a test for end of stream. And what read() returns, and how many bytes it is obliged to transfer.

Comment: I've started to comment 3 times already but this is just too much of a mess to do anything with.

Comment: Thanks, will take care of code formatting. Could someone suggests any solution for this issue?

Comment: Don't kid yourself. It's not just a matter of 'code formatting'. I pointed out at least four ***bugs*** in your code. Your edit doesn't fix any of them.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I didn't notice bug fixes. Is this process of verifying digital signature is correct? I took this code from Java site.